# Notes and attachment in Lead objects

Tags: related-list, notes

When a lead with notes and attachments in the related list is converted, does the files also saved in the account object? I haven't tried it yet. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, the notes and attachments on the Lead will be linked to the converted Account and Contact.

Here's the [salesforce reference](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005159)

> All notes and attachments from the lead are converted and attached to
>   the new account and contact. All open activities and activity history
>   from the lead are converted and attached to the new account, contact,
>   and opportunity

Comment: what is the soql request?